# wp_insert_post with POST data

Tags: forms, wp-insert-post

I found some code on this site for wp_insert_post and I got it working. I did find the post in the category where I would expect it to be. Then I changed the code example to include information from my form on the page and the code fails.

Here is the sample code I got from this site that does work.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['new_reservation']) == '1') {
    $post_title = "My Post";
    //$post_category = 'reservations';

    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_title'] = "My Post";
    $my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post.';
    $my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_author']   = 1;
    $my_post['post_category'] = array(9);

     wp_insert_post($my_post);
    //update_post_meta($post_id, 'reservations', $customer);

} ?>
```

so then I changed things to this in order to get the name of the post from the form

```
<form action="" method="post" name="reservations" id="reservations" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <table width="474" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="reserve">
        <tr>
            <td class="formTitles"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/name.png" alt="name" width="47" height="10" /></td>
            <td class="formTitles"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/date.png" alt="date" width="43" height="10" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="formInput"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>

                <input type="hidden" name="new_reservation" value="1" /><br />
            <td><input type="submit" name="reserveSubmit" id="reserveSubmit" class="button" value="submit"/> <span class="regularText"> or <a class="clearForm" href="#" onclick="reservation.reset();">Clear Form</a> </span></td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['new_reservation']) == '1') {
    $post_title = $_POST['name'];
    $post_category = 'reservations';

    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_title'] = $post_title;
    $my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post.';
    $my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_author']   = 1;
    $my_post['post_category'] = array(9);// Insert the post into the databasewp_insert_post( $my_post );"



     wp_insert_post($my_post);
    //update_post_meta($post_id, 'reservations', $customer);

} ?>
```

The code fails whenever I try to use the name variable as the name of the post

Comment: Show us the complete code, with the `wp_insert_post` line as well.  And, right before the `wp_insert_post`, do a `var_dump($my_post);` to see what is contained in the variable that you are inserting.

Comment: @cale_b I just edited the code above to show it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 'name' to something else. Because name is a reserved keyword in WordPress universe. [Check this and look for 'name' here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).